# Question about Cyclic Decomposition Theorem in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a f.d. vector space $V$ with minimal polynomial $p$. Then there exists $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in V$ s.t. $V=Z(\alpha_1;T)\oplus...\oplus Z(\alpha_n;T)$ and where $p_i$ is the generator of the polynomial ideal $\{f\in \mathbb{F}[x]:f(T)v=0\}$ and $p_{i+1}|p_i$ and $p_1=p$.

It turns out $p_i$ is equal to the minimal polynomial of $T$ restricted to $Z(\alpha_i;T)$, and $p_1...p_n=f$, the characteristic polynomial of $T$. But I want to know what each $p_i$ can possibly look like. My thought is that each $p_i$ has to be an irreducible factor of the minimal polynomial. So if $p=q_1^{b_1}...q_n^{b_n}$, then each $p_i$ has to be $q_j$ for some $j$. I was hoping someone could tell me whether or not this is correct.

Here's an example:

Now suppose you are given $p=(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^3$. We know that $p_1=p$. For $p_2$, we know $p_2$ is a factor of $p$, and since $f=p_1p_2p_3$ and $f$ and $m$ have the same prime factors, the only possibility is $p_2=(x-1)^a(x-2)^b(x-3)^c$, where $0\leq a\leq 1$, $0\leq b\leq 2$ and $0\leq c\leq 3$. But let's say $p_2=(x-1)(x-2)$. Then $p_2$ wouldn't be the unique generator of $\{f\in\mathbb{F}[X]:f(T)v=0\}$ (it would be either $x-1$ or $x-2$). Hence, $p_2$ has to be irreducible, so it is $x-1$, $x-2$, or $x-3$.

Comment: The *Jordan decomposition* theorem can be proven as a consequence of this one. You could work out the details for some easy matrices in Jordan normal form (almost diagonal, allowing some $1$'s just below the diagonal if the next culomn has the same diagonal element..). And, $p_2$ needs not be irreducible. Actually, because of the condition $p_{i+1}|p_i$, only the last one could  be irreducible.